# How to format timestamp with microsecond accuracy?

Tags: java, hive, timestamp

In keeping with SQL `TIMESTAMP(6)`, Hive `TIMESTAMP` supports microsecond precision. I am ingesting dates of the form `ddMMMyyyy:HH:mm:ss.uuuuuu` from a flat file, and inserting them into Hive `TIMESTAMP` fields. However, Java `DateFormatter` and `SimpleDateFormat` do not support time precision greater than milliseconds. How can I create a UDF that supports timestamps with microsecond precision?

Comment: You may have to do it in 2 steps, first get the time (create a timestamp object) then add the microseconds

Comment: Use the java.time classes that supplant the troublesome old date-time classes.

Comment: @BasilBourque, DateFormatter is in the java.time package. It does not support microseconds.

Comment: @user1332148 Incorrect. The java.time classes support [nanoseconds](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) for up to nine digits of decimal fraction of a second. This includes [`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). Please search Stack Overflow before posting. This has been covered many times already.